# Intent between layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I just start to develop in android and i'm trying to create new layout and connect between the old layout and the new layout with intent method, but i always got error
I will appreciate if someone can help me....

The code is :

```
package newapplication.com;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button b6;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        b6.setOnClickListener(next);

    //Call to the next activity
     OnClickListener next = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,       MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    };
}
```

It always write me that next cannot resolve to a variable

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting

Comment: You try to use next in b6.setOnClickListener(next) before it is created.

Comment: If you use eclipse, look in the menu : window >> show view >> Android >>logcat. You will see the logs of your phone then you can find the error. Without that you are blind and can't progress.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient handle a *single* `View` / `Button` click, is to do as shown below:

```
Button b6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
b6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Note that you are, in essence, doing the same but you are restricted by the sequential way that your code is interpreted.

All I did was take your `OnClickListener` instantiation and put it inside your `setOnClickListener()` method. Any other buttons in the layout would not be able to access this.

Comment: OK thanks for all the answers, i found the problem....i declare on b6 in the on create method

Comment: ??... If you answer was different then the ones provided can you please post an answer yourself, with your correction, and accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your code is almost correct. you have to define next *before* setting it as a listener and it will work.